# rosinstall_generator fails on OS X Maverick

Tags: ros, rosdistro, osx, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have recently tried to install ROS hydro on OS X with HomeBrew but the rosinstall_generator fails with:
(links looking like that , because had no enough karma to publish a link :))

> rosinstall_generator desktop_full
> --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only --tar > hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall_generator",
> line 117, in 
> rc = main()   File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall_generator",
> line 105, in main
> tar=args.tar)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall_generator/generator.py",
> line 189, in generate_rosinstall
> names, unknown_names = _classify_names(distro_name, names)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall_generator/generator.py",
> line 84, in _classify_names
> wet_distro = get_wet_distro(distro_name)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall_generator/generator.py",
> line 170, in get_wet_distro
> _wet_distro = _get_wet_distro(distro_name)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall_generator/distro.py",
> line 45, in get_distro
> return get_cached_distribution(index,
> distro_name)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosdistro/**init**.py",
> line 134, in get_cached_distribution
> cache = get_distribution_cache(index,
> dist_name)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosdistro/**init**.py",
> line 160, in get_distribution_cache
> yaml_gz_str = load_url(url, skip_decode=True)   File
> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosdistro/loader.py",
> line 59, in load_url
> raise URLError(str(e) + ' (%s)' % url) urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error
> <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor
> servname provided, or not known>
> (http: // ros.org / rosdistro / hydro-cache . yaml . gz)>

The problem is that it can't resolve the url: http: // ros . org / rosdistro / hydro-cache.yaml.gz.
I believe the rewrite rules are missing from the ros server, as http: // www . ros . org / rosdistro / hydro-cache.yaml.gz is reachable and http: // ros . org / rosdistro / hydro-cache.yaml.gz is not.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,
Csongor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141806/rosinstall_generator-fails-on-os-x-maverick/) by [zobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3498/zobi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can not reproduce this problem, it works just fine on OS X over here. And the cache without www is also reachable. Maybe it was a temporary problem. You could also try `pip install -U rosinstall_generator`, but I don't see how that should make much of a difference if the URL reachability is indeed the issue. Please double check that the URL is not reachable for you: `wget http://ros.org/rosdistro/hydro-cache.yaml.gz`.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zobi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3498/zobi/) on 2014-03-19**:
Thanks.That is right, now it works. Might have been a temporary issue.

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2014-07-09**:
Hello, I'm struggling with the same problem.

To double check I tried "wget..." as suggested above, and I get a message "-bash: wget: command not found"

[on Mac OS X Mavericks]

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-09**:
OSX doesn't have wget installed by default. You can use

```
curl
```

instead or install wget through homebrew:

```
brew install wget
```

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2014-07-09**:
@ahendrix thanks for your comment. I did directly paste it in the browser URL bar and I couldn't access it. however, i put a "www" between "http://" and "ros.", and I could download the cache.

It seems to be impossible to do so using rosintall_generator for me. Any ideas about a workaround?

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2014-07-09**:
Well, it turns out that the URL was not accessible from a secure wi-fi space even with access to it. I tried again after getting home from work and it runs fine.

Strange.

Thank you nevertheless.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-09**:
Are you certain you have the latest version of rosinstall_generator? I have version 0.1.9 on linux; the same version should work on OSX. You should be able to get your rosinstall_generator version with

```
python -c 'import rosinstall_generator; print rosinstall_generator.version'
```